# Npm install not working. Same error on Pc and Mac

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

Hello I am trying to create a Phonegap application and cannot seem to get my npm installers working.

```
    Davids-MBP:rentfinds davidthurman$ sudo npm start

> rentfinds@1.0.0 prestart /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds
> npm install


> fsevents@0.2.1 install /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:348:9: error: no type named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    v8::ThrowException(error);
    ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:355:53: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'; did you
      mean 'v8::TypeSwitch::New'?
    v8::Local<v8::Value> err = v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg));
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    v8::TypeSwitch::New
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:4704:28: note: 
      'v8::TypeSwitch::New' declared here
  static Local<TypeSwitch> New(Local<FunctionTemplate> type);
                           ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:355:69: error: calling a private constructor of class
      'v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>'
    v8::Local<v8::Value> err = v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg));
                                                                    ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: declared
      private here
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:357:65: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2,
      have 1
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~            ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:2496:3: note: 'New'
      declared here
  static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:357:26: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    obj->Set(v8::String::New("code"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:369:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:377:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:406:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:141:71: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_INLINE'
# define NAN_INLINE(declarator) inline __attribute__((always_inline)) declarator
                                                                      ^
../../nan/nan.h:416:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to
      'v8::Isolate *' for 1st argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to
      'v8::Isolate *' for 1st argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 2 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:420:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was
      provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: 
      candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:427:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:727:49: error: too few arguments to function call, single
      argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/davidthurman/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/v8.h:2930:3: note: 'New'
      declared here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:fsevents fsevents@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:fsevents Exit status 1
npm WARN lifecycle rentfinds@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) rentfinds@1.0.0 bower install /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds

> rentfinds@1.0.0 start /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds
> http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

sh: /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds/node_modules/.bin/http-server: Permission denied

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! rentfinds@1.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the rentfinds@1.0.0 start script 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the rentfinds package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls rentfinds
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/davidthurman/Desktop/Projects/rentfinds/npm-debug.log
Davids-MBP:rentfinds davidthurman$
```

Also whenever I try to run something like Bower it says "command not found"
I've tried with and without sudo. Ive gotten the same error on a mac and windows. I've looked around and can't seem to find anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: try with using sudo, or remove the nodejs and reinstall might be an version issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`fsevents` release page](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/releases), node v5 support didn't come until `fsevents` v1.0.3. FWIW v1.0.5 is the current release as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

jest-cli expected a lower version node. Upgrade jest-cli works for me (I am using node version 4.0.0)

```
npm install jest-cli --save-dev
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already used `sudo` to install `node` and `npm`. Check Your Current version `Node` and `NPM`. Upgrade it `NPM` to the latest version as `npm` version changes more frequently than `node` does. Also upgrade `Node` to the current stable version. For completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X) check :
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)