# Strange Benign Node.JS Errors/Warnings When I Install

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have ignored these for weeks now, and they seem to be piling up. My node app and everything work fine, but just when I run npm install for any node package it tends to print these. I have tried a node update and cache clean but nothing seems to remove these errors whenever I install a new package. Nothing exciting here and lots of repetition, but the full output is here:

How can I remove these errors?

Here is an excerpt:

```
> fsevents@0.2.1 install /Users/natumyers/Desktop/mine/A.M.E.N.SQL-Stack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));
```

Etcetera, and it continues to say:

```
                                       ^
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 2 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:420:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:427:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:727:49: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'isolate' was not specified
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Object::New();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/natumyers/.node-gyp/5.2.0/include/node/v8.h:2930:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:88:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:173:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/natumyers/Desktop/mine/A.M.E.N.SQL-Stack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v5.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:fsevents@0.2.1 fsevents@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:fsevents@0.2.1 Exit status 1
rt-ym-seq@0.0.0 /Users/natumyers/Desktop/mine/A.M.E.N.SQL-Stack
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-chrome-launcher@~0.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-coffee-preprocessor@~0.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-firefox-launcher@~0.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-html2js-preprocessor@~0.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-phantomjs-launcher@~0.1.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-requirejs@~0.2.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma-script-launcher@~0.1.0
└── passport-local@1.0.0 

npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-chrome-launcher@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-coffee-preprocessor@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-firefox-launcher@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-html2js-preprocessor@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-phantomjs-launcher@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-requirejs@~0.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma@0.10.10 requires a peer of karma-script-launcher@~0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON rt-ym-seq@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON rt-ym-seq@0.0.0 No license field.
~~~
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm install not working. Same error on Pc and Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864718/npm-install-not-working-same-error-on-pc-and-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In cases where package.json was created times back, you get this error because you have upgraded the `node` version.**

Downgrade the `node version` to whatever appropriate on which the `package.json` was created.

Here are steps to use older version of node

install `nvm` (`node version manager`)

`brew install nvm` for `os-x`

`apt-get install nvm` for `ubuntu`

`yum install nvm` for `red-hat`

considering you are on `mac`

Edit .bash_profile file to set `NVM_DIR` using `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

and append with

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"`

Open new `terminal` and install any specific node version

`nvm install v.0.10.26`

now try `npm install` you may not get the error if the node version is correct here.